# Fire Validation Rule before making SOAP callout

Tags: callout, validation-rule

On our Account object, we have a set of validation rules to maintain data quality. We also have created a custom VF page to override New button and call a custom function when the user clicks Save. This custom function makes a callout to other foreign system(SOAP service)via. continuation object, receives the response and then save the record. The issue now is since validation rules are fired only on save, there is a scope that invalid data gets entered to a foreign system and then Salesforce throws validation rule while saving record locally. This would create data inconsistency between two systems.
We cannot save the record and make callout in single transaction beacuse it would give an error  uncommitted data.

Is it possible to fire validation rule before making the callout without saving the record?

Comment: A more common approach here is to use an after insert/update trigger to queue the record for sync to the external system. You can use the `@future` annotation to allow callouts outside of the trigger context.

Comment: That is true but Continuation Object can only be called from Visualforce Page action method. In that case is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You don't need to use the continuation object in the @future context. Make a normal WebServiceCallout.Invoke SOAP callout. That way all the Salesforce validation will have completed first before attempting to create the record in the external system.